# Solandra / Elastic Search - full text searching (using Cassandra)

Tags: database, full-text-search, cassandra, elasticsearch, solandra

I'm using Cassandra for an app I am developing. I plan to use Solandra to query for documents. I am wondering if anyone has run into any way to use full text search in Solandra? Is there a way to get a hold of where documents are stored in Cassandra by querying for a Solandra id (where the document is stored in the index)?

For example:
I have a document, document A, that stores plain text. Suppose in document A I have plain text: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." I am assuming that Solandra would index document A. (document A could be stored in Cassandra) I want to search for "the lazy dog" through a Solandra query. Does Solandra return the location of doc A in the index or does it return the location of doc A in Cassandra db?

How does Solandra support this type of search? Does ElasticSearch/Solandra return the location of doc A in the index the engine built or does the engine return the location of the document in Cassandra? Suppose I want to get a lateral pointer to the Cassandra document  A, is there anyway to do this?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solandra does not support indexing data you insert into Cassandra.  For this you can keep your eye on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2915

With Solandra you would need to index your documents through the solr api.  Some folks do this, write to Cassandra and Solandra.